# Julia: how to see devectorized code?

Tags: julia

I would like to see devectorized code of some expression say [here](https://github.com/SimonDanisch/SchroedingersSmoke.jl/blob/master/src/MatlabPort.jl#L82)

```
obj.mask = exp.(1.0im*lambda*obj.dt/2.);
```

How one could print a generic expression in devectorized form in Julia?

Comment: When you say "devectorized form", do you mean valid Julia code that implements the same operation in (say) a `for` loop? Or do you mean the actual assembly code that the CPU will run, as output by the [`@code_native`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/InteractiveUtils/#InteractiveUtils.@code_native) macro?

Comment: @AhmedFasih:  Julia code that implements the same operation in (say) a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that what you ask for exists (please proof me wrong if I'm mistaken!).

The best you can do is use `@code_lowered, @code_typed, @code_llvm, @code_native` macros (in particular `@code_lowered`) to see what happens to your Julia code snippet. However, as Julia **isn't** translating all dots to explicit for loops internally, non of these snippets will show you a for-loop version of your code.

Example:

```
julia> a,b = rand(3), rand(3);

julia> f(a,b) = a.*b
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_lowered f(a,b)
CodeInfo(
1 1 ─ %1 = Base.Broadcast.materialize                                                                                           │
  │   %2 = Base.Broadcast.broadcasted                                                                                           │
  │   %3 = (%2)(Main.:*, a, b)                                                                                                  │
  │   %4 = (%1)(%3)                                                                                                             │
  └──      return %4                                                                                                            │
)
```

So, Julia translates the `.*` into a `Base.Broadcast.broadcasted` call. Of course, we can go further and do

```
julia> @which Base.Broadcast.broadcasted(Main.:*, a, b)
broadcasted(f, arg1, arg2, args...) in Base.Broadcast at broadcast.jl:1139
```

and check `broadcast.jl` in line 1139  and so on to trace the actual `broadcasted` method that will be called (maybe Tim Holy's [Rebugger](https://github.com/timholy/Rebugger.jl) is useful here :D). But as I said before, there won't be a for-loop in it. Instead you will find something like this:

```
broadcasted(::DefaultArrayStyle{1}, ::typeof(*), r::AbstractRange, x::Number) = range(first(r)*x, step=step(r)*x, length=length(r))
broadcasted(::DefaultArrayStyle{1}, ::typeof(*), r::StepRangeLen{T}, x::Number) where {T} =
    StepRangeLen{typeof(T(r.ref)*x)}(r.ref*x, r.step*x, length(r), r.offset)
broadcasted(::DefaultArrayStyle{1}, ::typeof(*), r::LinRange, x::Number) = LinRange(r.start * x, r.stop * x, r.len)
```

**Update**

Ok, eventually, I found for-loops in `copyto!` in `broadcast.jl`. But this is probably to deep into the rabbit hole.

Comment: Is it possible to do such introspection/code generation via [reflection](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.0/devdocs/reflection/#Expansion-and-lowering-1)?